# Properly disposing an object hierarchy in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable, finalize

I am working on a project where a certain class hierarchy implements IDisposable.

Some of the classes also implement a Finalize method ( ~MyClass() )

In general it looks something like this:

```
public class BaseClass : IDisposable
{
}

public class SomeClass : BaseClass
{
    ~SomeClass()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    Dispose()
    {
        // Do some stuff.
        base.Dispose();
    }
}

public class AnoterClass : SomeClass
{
    ~AnoterClass()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    Dispose()
    {
        // Do some stuff.
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I'd like to know what is the proper way of handling calls to Dispose, as it seems that these objects are being disposed by calling Dispose(), and later on crash since the Finalize method is called.

Is it best to keep a flag at the lowest class in the hierarchy (protected bool disposed), and check that in every level of the class hierarchy?

I find that every possible solution requires some code duplication, which is not what i'm after.

Comment: A complex hierarchy holding unmanaged resources seems weird. You should probably hold the unmanaged resources in simple `SafeHandle`s, and avoid finalizers in your complex object graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to suppress finalization if you are manually disposing of your objects.

The pattern to follow is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Edit:

I think you only need to implement at a particular level of class hierarchy if you have something new to dispose at that level, otherwise I believe that the disposal in the base class will do everything that you need.  If your implementation in any particular class just calls `base.Dispose(disposing)` then it is not needed, if it has to do some clean uop, then call `base.Dispose()` then you need it.

Having a protected flag as you suggest should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with the pattern, the question is- should it be implemented across all levels of a class hiehrarchy? Isn't there any easier option?

Comment: You should update your examples with the pattern you are actually using as the reason you're getting your crash is because you are not implementing the pattern correctly, and are not suppressing the garbage collectors call to the finalize method after you have manually disposed.

Answer (score 4):

If your base class implements the [standard IDisposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), all you need to do is add the `Dispose(bool disposing)` override to each derived class that itself owns `IDisposable` or unmanaged resources:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Release managed resources
        }
        // Release unmanaged resources
    }
    finally
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't implement finalizers in any of the derived classes.

And, of course, any classes in the hierarchy that don't have their own `IDisposable` resources don't need this override.

Comment: +1 for a much clearer description and example of what I was trying to say!

Comment: Unless the whole purpose of the class centers around an unmanaged resource, there probably shouldn't be finalizers in *any* of the classes within its hierarchy.  Instead, any resource that would need finalization-based cleanup should be encapsulated within its own object whose purpose centers around that resource.  If an object's finalizer isn't suppressed, it will cause every object to which it holds a direct or indirect strong reference to be kept alive for another GC cycle.  Finalizable objects should thus avoid holding references to outside objects not needed for cleanup.